# Pythonic way of changing function arguments inside the function

Tags: python, function, arguments

Let's say that I have a list of integer arguments in a function, and I want to add 1 to each one of them. Is there a clean way of doing such, something like this pseudo-code:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    for argument in arguments:
        argument += 1
    ...
```

In particular, I want to avoid explicitly referencing each of these arguments inside the code, and just iterate over all the arguments. Changing the function arguments to just a list is not an option, since `a, b, c` have a specific meaning inside the code.

Comment: If you're expecting that to have any effect outside the function, you need to read up on [how Python variables and assignment work](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: In my case, I don't really care about the values outside the function.

Comment: But then for what will you use these? Since integers are immutable, you cannot simply alter the variables with which you made the call, so what are you aiming to do?

Comment: It would help if you were to explain what is the real problem you are trying to solve here in which you are trying to do this?

Comment: This was a simplification of my real function, for which an answer is non-dependent on the usage. For completeness, I need to round the values before calling another function. I cannot do such in the function calling `foo` since I have no control over that codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## With *explicit referencing*

A *clean* way to do this is probably using *iterable unpacking* and a mapping, like:

```
def foo(a,b,c):
    a,b,c = map(lambda x:x+1,(a,b,c))
    # ...
```

Or for rounding:

```
 def foo(a,b,c):
     a,b,c = map(round,(a,b,c))
     # ...
```

Since this is still *explicit*, and furthermore keeps the parameters in the function signature of `foo`.

You can of course use `*args` and `**kwargs` and manipulate these (directly), but that could result in losing information about what the parameters `a`, `b` and `c` mean (their semantics).

## Using a *decorator* (apply the function on *all* parameters)

Another way to do it, that will remove the semantics of the parameters is using a *decorator*:

```
def apply_func_args(func):
    def dec(f):
        def g(*args,**kwargs):
            return f(*map(func,args),**{k:func(v) for k,v in kwargs.items()})
        g.__name__ = f.__name__
        g.__doc__ = f.__doc__
        return g
    return dec
```

Then you can *put the decorator on `foo`*, like:

```
@apply_func_args(round)
def foo(a,b,c):
    # ...
```

Now if you call `foo(1.4,1.3,1.9)`, `foo` will obtain `(a,b,c) == (1,1,2)`. For example, if you want to `print` `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
>>> def apply_func_args(func):
...     def dec(f):
...         def g(*args,**kwargs):
...             return f(*map(func,args),**{k:func(v) for k,v in kwargs.items()})
...         g.__name__ = f.__name__
...         g.__doc__ = f.__doc__
...         return g
...     return dec
... 
>>> @apply_func_args(round)
... def foo(a,b,c):
...     print((a,b,c))
... 
>>> foo(1.4,1.3,1.9)
(1, 1, 2)
>>> foo(1.4,2.5,c=0)
(1, 2, 0)
>>> foo(b=1.4,a=2.5,c=0)
(2, 1, 0)
```

So here we defined a clean way to apply the function (`round`) on *all* named and unnamed parameters of `foo`. As a result, if we call `foo`, `foo` will always obtain rounded values.

Comment: Can this be done without explicitly referencing each of the arguments? I tried using a for loop with both `*args` and `**kwargs`, but both are syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @DaniyalShahrokhian: yes, you can use a decorator, like demonstrated. This will apply the function to *all* parameters.

Comment: Very complete answer @Willem. I think if there is no simpler implementation, I will go with the explicit referencing. I was hoping that in python there was a way to just reference the function arguments similarly to my pseudo-code, but I think that defying a decorator for just one function seems overkill.

Comment: @DaniyalShahrokhian: well you can of course reuse the decorator. Furthermore I think you still have to make it *explicit* what you are doing (not per se by referencing the variables, but it should be clear what is happening).

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    return call_other(round(a),round(b),round(c))
```

or

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    return call_other(a+1,b+1,c+1)
```

I think if i am understanding what you are trying to do... (from reading the comments)

Comment: The main reason I posted this question was to avoid explicitly referencing each one of the arguments. My concern was on a clean way to do it, instead of having multiple mentions of the function `round()` and variables `a, b, c`.

Comment: explicit is better than implicit

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with no side-effects:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
c = [9, 8, 7, 6]
def foo(*args):
    modified = list()
    for idx, arg in enumerate(args):
        modified.append([x + 1 for x in arg])
    print modified
    # do something else

# In [17]: foo(a, b, c)
# [[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 9, 8, 7]]
```

With this implementation you can input as many arrays as you like.

Comment: This solution would kill the readability of the function, since the arguments stop having a meaning. I modified my question to reflect that the arguments are not just meaningless integers.